# Navigate to an external URL in rally app

Tags: rally

I want to build an app that works like "custom URL app" where I can select several URLs from a dropdown to navigate to

Sounds like very simple, but I can't find the way to make external navigation within Rally apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself

By using the javascript

```
window.location.replace('http://www.bing.com');
```